# React How change JQUERY by function or request

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to know how can I do to change a Jquery request by a function or fetch request.

I'm trying to create a connection with OpenId using React, this code works, but I want to know how I could make same $.ajax function without $.ajax and change other methods that are using $, like in display method.

Sorry, I'm new with React and I dont have much experience. Should I change $.ajax by fetch??? And if is true, how insert params inside fetch request??

If is possible, could you show me a solution example.

I want to change this ajax request form a method, function or request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:60136/values',
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: headers
}).then(function (data) {
  this.display('.js-api-result', data);
}).catch( (error) => {
  this.display('.js-api-result', {
    status: error.status,
    statusText: error.statusText,
    response: error.responseJSON
  });
});
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
/* eslint-disable no-alert, no-console */
import $ from 'jquery';
import { UserManager, Log } from 'oidc-client';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.manager = null;
        this.user = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var settings = {
            authority: 'https://localhost:44300',
            client_id: 'js',
            popup_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:56668/popup.html',
            silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:56668/silent-renew.html',
            post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:56668/index.html',
            response_type: 'id_token token',
            scope: 'openid profile email api',
            accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 4,
            automaticSilentRenew: true,
            filterProtocolClaims: true
        };
        this.manager = new UserManager(settings);
        Log.logger = console;

        this.manager.events.addUserLoaded( (loadedUser) => {
            this.user = loadedUser;
            this.display('.js-user', this.user);
        });
        this.manager.events.addSilentRenewError( (error) => {
            console.error('error while renewing the access token', error);
        });
        this.manager.events.addUserSignedOut( () => {
            alert('The user has signed out');
        });
    }

    handleLogin = () => {
        this.manager
        .signinPopup()
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error('error while logging in through the popup', error);
        });
    }

    handleCallAPI = () => {
        var headers = {};
        if (this.user && this.user.access_token) {
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.user.access_token;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:60136/values',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: headers
        }).then(function (data) {
            this.display('.js-api-result', data);
        }).catch( (error) => {
            this.display('.js-api-result', {
                status: error.status,
                statusText: error.statusText,
                response: error.responseJSON
            });
        });
    }

    handleLogout = () => {
        this.manager
        .signoutRedirect()
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error('error while signing out user', error);
        });
    }

    display(selector, data) {
        if (data && typeof data === 'string') {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
        }
        if (data) {
            data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        }
        $(selector).text(data);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="">
                <div className="nav-bar">
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">OpenId Example</a>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>

                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                <li className="nav-item active">
                                    <button className="btn btn-dark js-login" onClick={this.handleLogin} >Login</button>

                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item active">
                                    <button className="btn btn-dark js-call-api" onClick={this.handleCallAPI} >Call API</button>

                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <button className="btn btn-dark js-logout" onClick={this.handleCallAPI} >Logout</button>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <div className="container main-container">
                    <div className="row">

                        <div className="col-6">
                            <div className="panel panel-default">
                                <div className="panel-heading">User data</div>
                                <div className="panel-body">
                                    <pre className="js-user"></pre>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-6">
                            <div className="panel panel-default">
                                <div className="panel-heading">API call result</div>
                                <div className="panel-body">
                                    <pre className="js-api-result"></pre>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write you ajax with fetch like

```
let url = 'http://localhost:60136/values';
 fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers}).
  then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
       this.display('.js-api-result', data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.display('.js-api-result', error);
    });
```

You can also use third party library 
[axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to handel ajax reaquest

https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Thanks! :D I'm going to try with both.. your code and practice with axios